# Regarding dir()

Tags: python, function, module, dir

Initially I was trying to find `dir(re)` but realized I had quotes.

### Edit for clarity:

Wouldn't `"re"` be a string? So `dir("re") == dir(string)`? The output isn't the same. That is essentially what I am wondering.

### Edit for comments:

I might misunderstand but doesn't `dir` return a list of all the functions within the module? Also when I call `dir` on `"re"` it gives me a list of functions. No error is returned.

edit2: yes `dir`. Been switching between a ruby and python project and for some reason I had def on the brain. sorry xD

Comment: I don't understand your question.  `def("re")` is not valid Python code.  You also switch between talking about modules and functions, and then you have a totally different question at the end, which also is unclear.  Please clarify what you're asking.

Comment: Maybe you mean **dir**, which returns a list of names in a given scope? You will still need to filter out functions manually.
e.g. by iterating over all names and check against `type(x) == types.FunctionType`

Comment: Did you somehow manage to write `def` where you meant `dir` almost ten times?

Comment: Read [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir), dir(obj) returns "a list of valid attributes" for object `obj`. And everything in python is an object, be it a module `re`, or a string `'re'`.

Comment: Regarding your updated question: `dir("re")` _is_ the same as `dir(str)`. Note that the type of strings in Python is `<type 'str'>` -- try `print type("re")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need is a clarification on what `dir` does.

[`dir`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#dir) is a Python built-in function that does either one of two things, depending on whether an argument is supplied or not:

1. Without an argument, it returns a list of the names in the current scope.  These names are represented as strings.
2. With an argument, it returns a list of the attributes and methods that belong to that argument.  Once again, it will be a list of strings.

Below is a demonstration of the first action:

```
>>> num = 1 # Just to demonstrate
>>> dir()
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', 'num']
>>>
```

And here is a demonstration of the second:

```
>>> dir(str)
['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__getnewargs__', '__getslice__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__mod__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rmod__', '__rmul__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '_formatter_field_name_split', '_formatter_parser', 'capitalize', 'center', 'count', 'decode', 'encode', 'endswith', 'expandtabs', 'find', 'format', 'index', 'isalnum', 'isalpha', 'isdigit', 'islower', 'isspace', 'istitle', 'isupper', 'join', 'ljust', 'lower', 'lstrip', 'partition', 'replace', 'rfind', 'rindex', 'rjust', 'rpartition', 'rsplit', 'rstrip', 'split', 'splitlines', 'startswith', 'strip', 'swapcase', 'title', 'translate', 'upper', 'zfill']
>>>
```

Moreover, if its argument is a Python module, then `dir` will list the names contained in that module:

```
>>> import sys
>>> dir(sys)
['__displayhook__', '__doc__', '__excepthook__', '__name__', '__package__', '__stderr__', '__stdin__', '__stdout__', '_clear_type_cache', '_current_frames', '_getframe', '_mercurial', 'api_version', 'argv', 'builtin_module_names', 'byteorder', 'call_tracing', 'callstats', 'copyright', 'displayhook', 'dllhandle', 'dont_write_bytecode', 'exc_clear', 'exc_info', 'exc_type', 'excepthook', 'exec_prefix', 'executable', 'exit', 'flags', 'float_info', 'float_repr_style', 'getcheckinterval', 'getdefaultencoding', 'getfilesystemencoding', 'getprofile', 'getrecursionlimit',
'getrefcount', 'getsizeof', 'gettrace', 'getwindowsversion', 'hexversion', 'long_info', 'maxint', 'maxsize', 'maxunicode', 'meta_path', 'modules', 'path', 'path_hooks', 'path_importer_cache', 'platform', 'prefix', 'ps1', 'ps2', 'py3kwarning', 'setcheckinterval', 'setprofile', 'setrecursionlimit', 'settrace', 'stderr', 'stdin', 'stdout', 'subversion', 'version', 'version_info',
'warnoptions', 'winver']
>>>
```

---

Now, you said in your question that the output of `dir("re")` was not equal to `dir(string)`.  There are a few things I would like to say about this:

1. If `string` is a string literal, as in `dir("string")`, then it *should* work:

   ```
   >>> dir("re") == dir("string")
   True
   >>>
   ```
2. If `"re"` is actually the [`re`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) module, then the behavior you are seeing is expected since the module is *not* a string.
3. If you were expecting `dir("re")` to list the names contained in the `re` module, then you are mistaken.  You cannot reference the module with a string.  Instead, you have to explicitly import it first:

   ```
   >>> dir("re")  # The output is the same as doing dir(str)
   ['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__getnewargs__', '__getslice__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__mod__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rmod__', '__rmul__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '_formatter_field_name_split', '_formatter_parser', 'capitalize', 'center', 'count', 'decode', 'encode', 'endswith', 'expandtabs', 'find', 'format', 'index', 'isalnum', 'isalpha', 'isdigit', 'islower', 'isspace', 'istitle', 'isupper', 'join', 'ljust', 'lower', 'lstrip', 'partition', 'replace', 'rfind', 'rindex', 'rjust', 'rpartition', 'rsplit', 'rstrip', 'split', 'splitlines', 'startswith', 'strip', 'swapcase', 'title', 'translate', 'upper', 'zfill']
   >>>
   >>> import re
   >>> dir(re) # The output is for the re module, not str
   ['DEBUG', 'DOTALL', 'I', 'IGNORECASE', 'L', 'LOCALE', 'M', 'MULTILINE', 'S', 'Scanner', 'T', 'TEMPLATE', 'U', 'UNICODE', 'VERBOSE', 'X', '_MAXCACHE', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__version__', '_alphanum', '_cache', '_cache_repl', '_compile', '_compile_repl', '_expand', '_pattern_type', '_pickle', '_subx', 'compile', 'copy_reg', 'error', 'escape', 'findall',  'finditer', 'match', 'purge', 'search', 'split', 'sre_compile', 'sre_parse', 'sub', 'subn', 'sys', 'template']
   >>>
   ```